# Which code's perfomance is better?

Tags: java, performance

I have two same conditions and i want to know which is well in perfomance ?

```
if(str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1) == 'a'
    || str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1) == 'b' )
{
    // body 
}
```

--------------------OR--------------------

```
char temp = str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1);
if( temp == 'a' || temp == 'b')
{
    // body
}
```

Comment: The real question is which is _more readable_? :)

Comment: Talking about readable ... How about ... `.endsWith("a")` ?

Comment: Caring about performance for such a  miniscule detail is like mowing the lawn with a nail scissor.

Comment: Yup Thanks to all... i was just thinkin about the memory as i had created a temp variable and i had many such or conditions in a single if... Now i think the second is much better , its worth creatin a variable... thanks to all again...

Comment: If you create even one object it will be more than 10x more expensive than operations like this. I would suggest you profile your application first, and maybe reducing the number of objects you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option would be faster and also much more readable, however better to use some other name than 'temp'

Answer (score 2):

The second version is a *tiny little bit* faster.

**Reason:**
2 method calls less (if it doesn't end with 'a').
But both do not much more than `return variable;`:

- `charAt()` is only an access to a array, and
- the `length()` of the string is already pre-computed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Second code is better option as str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1) is just performed once in worst case also.

```
char temp = str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1);

if( temp == 'a' || temp == 'b')
{
  // body
}
```

In the other case str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1) has to be performed twice.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the same performance, as an optimizing compiler (or just in time compiler/hotspot) could change the 1st version to the 2nd at compile time.

Comment: This is true.  And even if it doesn't, the next generation of the compiler might do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second option because it is easier to read. Also `str_final.length()` and `str_final.charAt()` are only called once.

In addition, instead of calling the char `temp`, call it something more meaningful like `lastChar`.

You might even consider using a switch statement if you have more than just two characters to check:

```
char lastChar = str_final.charAt(str_final.length() -1);
switch (lastChar) {
  case 'a':
  case 'b':
    //do something
    break;
  case 'c':
    //something else
    break;
  case 'd':
    //something else
    break;
}
```

Comment: obviously i'll call it last_char but just here i named so ...sorry:)

Comment: in Java, the convention is to use camelCase

Answer (score 0):

The second piece of code is faster because `.charAt` and `.length()` are evaluated only once. As others pointed out, readability is clearly more important though, which is also favouring the second solution.

Comment: I am curious to find out what machine code is emitted by HotSpot for the scenario with two calls to `charAt` and `length`...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a catch question? I would certainly prefer the second construct because it's way more readable, and probably performs better.

The compiler can easily optimize temporary variables away, but cannot determine if a function call has sideeffects. So the double function call cannot be optimized to one single call.

Answer (score 0):

The second one can't be slower, so I suppose I'd say the second one, as it avoids a method call at least. But, the JIT is going to inline this. The performance difference is going to be all but negligible unless this is in a very tight loop.

I personally find the *second* more readable as well (perhaps if you called the variable something other than 'temp'). So I'd vote for it on those grounds. But that's the better question here I think: which is clearer? Worry about performance when you have any reason to believe this is code matters.

Answer (score 0):

Second version better, though it has a tiny performance than first, it also has couple of advantages
1. Readability
2. Maintenance - For this type of code, suppose if you have to check for more conditions(say 10), then to change the logic, just one place.